# is homepage url and homepage url + / ever different?

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, uri, filepath

Let's say we have a site that's test.com, would test.com/ ever be a different site/file then test.com? I know that the url represents a path to the server to get that file. Going to  test.com/file and test.com/file/ could potentially bring up different sites since the latter is a directory. So I was wondering if the same is true for the root.

Or am wrong about the url as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the url represents a path to the server to get that file

This is correct, but this can be any path you choose.

When you create a simple website with nested folders yes you can create something like this:

```
/webroot/index.html
        /blog.html
        /myvideos/list.html
```

Which results in for example `www.example.com`, `www.example.com/blog.html` and `www.example.com/myvideos/list.html`

But with some server side settings called [rewrites](https://www.google.com/search?q=mod%20rewrite&oq=mod%20rewrite&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i65l2j69i60l2j69i65.1815j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you can make your url behave like anything you want.

I could even redirect urls to entire different servers. Or make 2 different urls go to the same path. Anything you want.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your environment and how it handles the routing. Many frameworks treat url/ and url as aliases, but many frameworks don't. So the answer to your question is yes, it can be different.